# useReducer: Clone unchanged values too?

Tags: reactjs

If I'm setting up a reducer with this state:

```
const initialCoursesState = {
  selected: [],
  disabled: [],
  hidden: [],
};
```

Can I write my reducer like this, where I keep the `disabled` and `hidden` arrays the same:

```
function coursesReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_COURSE':
      return {
        ...state,
        selected: [ ...state.selected, action.payload ],
      };
    case 'REMOVE_COURSE':
      return {
        ...state,
        selected: state.selected.filter(s => s !== action.payload),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Or do I need to clone `disabled` and `hidden` too, even though they're not changing:

```
function coursesReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_COURSE':
      return {
        ...state,
        selected: [ ...state.selected, action.payload ],
        disabled: [ ...state.disabled ],
        hidden: [ ...state.hidden ],
      };
    case 'REMOVE_COURSE':
      return {
        ...state,
        selected: state.selected.filter(s => s !== action.payload),
        disabled: [ ...state.disabled ],
        hidden: [ ...state.hidden ],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: You only want to update the reference for properties that have changed and their parents. This allows you to use reference comparisons to check if a section of data in your state has changed. So the first example would be better.

Comment: This bit of the documentation from [Redux](https://redux.js.org/faq/immutable-data#what-are-the-benefits-of-immutability) could help shed some light on this for you. I know this question is about useReducer, but alot of the reasoning that doesn't relate directly to Redux's inner workings still applies.

Comment: @JacobSmit That makes sense. I wouldn't want unrelated effects to re-run

Comment: Yep, cloning those unchanged arrays could lead you to extra re-renders or hooks running more often that you would like.